# Dynamically Configure a Topojson Projection's Scale to Maximize Space of SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have a projection of a single county that is called dynamically through a function. I need to set the `.scale()` to match the varying sizes of counties for my particular application, however my question is also relevant to any use case where projections scales need to integrate with a dynamic environment.

Mark created an excellent example to illustrate my earlier problem of dynamically projecting counties:

```
function draw() {

      var topo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allCounties));

      var someCounties = [24005, 24013, 24025, 24019, 24043, 24015, 24041, 24023],
        rand = someCounties[Math.floor(Math.random() * someCounties.length)];

      var geoCounty = topo.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) {
        return d.id === rand;
      });

      topo.objects.counties.geometries = geoCounty;

      var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
        .translate([0, 0])
        .scale(20000);

      var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

      var county = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.counties),
        bounds = path.bounds(county);

      projection
        .translate([width / 2 - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2, height / 2 - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2]);

      countyPath
        .datum(county)
        .attr("class", "county")
        .attr("d", path);

      setTimeout(draw, 2000);
    }
```

Full code here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/w3yeCT0VTlx0IlUHLZG6?p=preview

The above example has projections of the state of Maryland. My own use case is actually *all* counties. The counties of Maryland are relatively small, so `.scale(20000)` is suitable. However, other counties can be much larger, resulting in the projection to go out of the bounds of the SVG it was appended to.

So my question is thus:

Given the task of dynamic projections and a static svg of size:

```
var width = 500,
  height = 300;
```

How can I dynamically change `.scale()` so that the bounds of the county will maximize the svg space (vertically or horizontally) but not exceed the bounds of the svg?

It seems like a simple algebra based 'solve for X' type of problem, but I'm having immense trouble understanding how `bounds` even works. It seems to start in a different place with each polygon. Please advise,

Thank you

Comment: This is a duplicate (answered by Mr. Bostock himself!).  I've applied his answer to my plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJd2bD3z6YAx2rRSvomt?p=preview).  Enjoy!

Comment: Oh that's a surprise, a pleasant one.Thank you for pointing that out to me. I phrased the question a bit differently, I suppose that's why I didn't see any immediate posts on this. Cool plunker!